# Ubuntu Installer only detects 1 of my 2 SSDs

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my 120GB ssd but the installer can't detect the partitions made on Disk 0, It only detects the disk with Windows installed on it. The partitions are as seen below. note: I had installed Ubuntu 22.04 before and the same way and never encountered this problem. After deleting Ubuntu 22.04 to install the version I need, I began running into this problem and can't seem to find a similar situation on the internet.
Yes, my storage is using RAID. Neither of the disks is dynamic.

Screenshot of partitions:

[image: screenshot of partitions]

Comment: Are you sure you want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.. It was released in 2018-April (why it's 18.04 using the *year.month* format) with 5 years of *standard* support; thus is in its final *weeks* of standard support. Are you expecting to use this system only days/weeks?

Comment: What Raid 0, 1, 2, 3 or 5

Comment: @David It is Raid0.

Comment: @guiverc I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 to be able to use ROS melodic which is unsupported in later versions.

Comment: RAID 0 (disk striping) is the process of dividing a body of data into blocks and spreading the data blocks across multiple storage devices,  This is most likely what you are seeing.

Comment: @tryingtolearn is there a reason not using ROS Noetic, it is far more developed and standard on ROS1. Then you can use Ubuntu 20.04